# sys.exitfunc not working in python

Tags: python, sys, shutdown-hook, atexit

I am trying to run following simple code

```
import sys

print("Starting Test Python Module");

def testmethod():
    print("From test method")

sys.exitfunc = testmethod
print("Terminating Test Python Module");
```

and it prints

```
C:\Users\athakur\Softwares>python test.py
Starting Test Python Module
Terminating Test Python Module
```

I am not able to understand why it does not print "From Test method"

Using atexit works fine though

```
import atexit

print("Starting Test Python Module");

def testmethod():
    print("From test method")

atexit.register(testmethod)
print("Terminating Test Python Module");
```

Outputs

```
C:\Users\athakur\Softwares>python test.py
Starting Test Python Module
Terminating Test Python Module
From test method
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.exitfunc` [does not exist](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable) in Python 3.x.

Comment: Yes I am using `Python 3.4.3`. So this would explain the behavior. But shouldn't python interpreter complaint about it?

Comment: The protection against arbitrary attributes being added to objects of *types* defined in C apparently doesn't apply to modules. Should it? Possibly.

Comment: @AniketThakur No, you are simply setting an attribute `exitfunc` to `sys` module, there is nothing wrong about that. You can do `sys.blahblahblah = <something>` , and it would work ( as long as something is defined :-) , like it works for most other objects in python) .

Answer (score 6):

[`sys.exitfunc`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exitfunc) is deprecated since python2.4 and was [removed in python3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/search.html?q=sys.exitfunc&check_keywords=yes&area=default).